# Como agregar clase base a modelo django existente

Tags: django-models

Tengo en producción la clase A con instancias, y quiero agregarle una clase base B, actualmente :

```
class A:
    name = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    phone = models.TextField(max_length=30)
```

y lo que necesito es:

```
class B:
    name = models.TextField(max_length=1000)

class A(B):
    phone = models.TextField(max_length=30)
```

El problema es que al hacer esto, cuando hago el makemigrations me pide un valor para b_ptr ( lo que no me queda claro que es, y si pongo nulo o un numero cualquiera no funciona)

"You are trying to add a non-nullable field '**b_ptr**' to **a** without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows)"

Agradezco si me pueden dar una mano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lo que quieres hacer se llama herencia, lo que pasa es que al hace `class A(B)` se creado dos tablas A y B y para relacionar A con B en A se crea un FK `nametable_ptr` con B, opciones para corregir tu problema:

1. Elimina todos los registros que tengas en A, ya que si tienes registros no puede crear un campo FK con null por que  es obligatorio
2. Antes de hacer la herencia crea la tabla B y añade un registro por ejemplo con el id=1, luego haces la herencia y cuando te  pida un valor por defecto le dices que 1, es el id del registro que añadiste  en la tabla B
3. Si no te funcionan ninguna de las dos anteriores vas a tener que eliminar la tabla A y volver a crearla, para que tengas problemas con los archivos de migración no elimines la tabla directamente desde la BD sino comenta el modelo A corre las migraciones para que elimine la tabla, luego descomenta vuelve a correr las migraciones para que cree la tabla con la herencia.

Comment: Se soluciono con la opción 1, es decir, fue necesario borrar todas las instancias de A, para posteriormente hacer la herencia y luego la migración.

Answer (score 0):

La forma más sencilla es eliminar los ficheros de migraciones que están en la carpeta migrations.
Elimina solo los que están numerados. De esa forma se realiza la migración como si fuera la primera vez.
Ten en cuenta que esto lo puedes hacer en caso que no te interesen los datos acumulados
Una vez eliminados los archivos de migraciones vuelves a ejecuta makemigrations [app]